# USB host controllers broken on every reboot

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, device-manager, usb-hub

Something happened (including Windows Updates?) and now every time I reboot, most of my USB host controllers/root hubs are not working:

[image: broken]

The broken ones say:

> This device cannot start. (Code 10)
>
> Windows did not start a related device driver. To learn more, click
>   the Driver tab and then click Driver Details.

I've tried uninstalling all USB devices (including grayed out ones) and rebooting many times, doing a System Restore (which failed to complete and also didn't fix anything), etc.

After a reboot, if I disable and then enable each host controller, they start working again:

[image: fixed]

But then on reboot most are broken again.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you think it was an update (or something else software-related) that caused it, try using System Restore to go back to a point before it happened. But really, that's weird enough to appear to be a hardware problem.  To confirm/deny that idea, have you tried a fresh install of Windows with all drivers updated to latest?  If so and it keeps happening then you have a USB hardware failure.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Already tried System Restore and it just screwed up all my files.  :/

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Or I could use a Windows 7 boot disk if such a thing exists?

Answer (score 0):

I never found a cause or solution to this, but I made a workaround batch file, scheduled to run on computer start:

```
"FULL_PATH_TO\devcon.exe" disable "PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4396"*
"FULL_PATH_TO\devcon.exe" disable "PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4397"*
"FULL_PATH_TO\devcon.exe" disable "PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4398"*
"FULL_PATH_TO\devcon.exe" disable "PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4399"*

"FULL_PATH_TO\devcon.exe" enable "PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4396"*
"FULL_PATH_TO\devcon.exe" enable "PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4397"*
"FULL_PATH_TO\devcon.exe" enable "PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4398"*
"FULL_PATH_TO\devcon.exe" enable "PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4399"*

"FULL_PATH_TO\devcon.exe" enable USB*
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13269904/125507

http://delphintipz.blogspot.com/2012/07/disable-failed-no-devices-disabled.html

http://ccm.net/faq/1886-enable-disable-a-device-from-the-command-line